# Multiple Arrays, Combine Into One, Get the Mean d3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I have a function that loops through my json objects and pushes them into an Array. Here is an example of one of the objects. Each object will have the exact same keys for stats--but of course, different values. I need to loop through all the arrays and add up the stats then divide them by the number of arrays. Of course, I could do this with a few loop functions....but since i'm using d3, I figured I'd try and figure out what is built in, which is d3. mean(). Is there a way to grab all values in all arrays and average them in d3?

```
{
        "name": "Mr Man",
        "position": "G",
        "image": "img/mrman.jpg",
        "stats": {
            "GP": 35,
            "Min": 567,
            "Points": 191,
            "Rebounds": 46,
            "Assists": 72,
            "Steals": 18,
            "Blocks": 1,
            "Turnovers": 37,
            "FGAtt": 151,
            "FGMade": 63,
            "TPtAtt": 55,
            "TPMade": 18,
            "FTAtt": 47,
            "FTMade": 71
        }
        // doing this works but it's very inefficient...I should be able to loop this
        var tempdata = playerArr.slice()
    console.log(tempdata + "tempdata")


    function meanVal(value) {
        return d3.mean(tempdata, function(d) {
        return d.stats[value] })
    }
    var avgArray = {};
    avgArray.GP = meanVal('GP');
    avgArray.Min = meanVal('Min');
    avgArray.FGMade = meanVal('FGMade');
    avgArray.FGAtt = meanVal('FGAtt');
    avgArray.TPMade = meanVal('TPMade');
    avgArray.TPAtt = meanVal('TPAtt');
    avgArray.Points = meanVal('Points');
    avgArray.Rebounds = meanVal('Rebounds');
    avgArray.Assists = meanVal('Assists');
    avgArray.Turnovers = meanVal('Turnovers');
    avgArray.Steals = meanVal('Steals');
    avgArray.Blocks = meanVal('Blocks');

    console.log(avgArray.Min + "ar")
```

Something like this doesn't work...maybe because I have it focusing on multiple arrays instead of just one array:

```
function returnMean(value) {
        return d3.mean(playerArr.stats, function(d) {
        return d [value] })
    }

    var myMean = returnMean('Points');
    console.log(myMean)
            console.log(playerArr.length) // returns more than 1, say 2 or 3 or 4
```

I may have had to use splice in this case:
        var tempdata = playerArr.slice()
        function returnMean(value) {
            return d3.mean(tempdata, function(d) {
            return d.stats[value] })
        }

Comment: It sounds like you would need `d.stats[value]` and not `d[value]`.

Comment: The issue is, my stats 'array' is actually an object as you can see...playerArr.stats,function(d){ return d.stats [value] }) doesn't work....nor does playerArr, function(d) {return d.stats[value] })

Comment: I think I may have solved it? I had to use splice: var tempdata = playerArr.slice()